# get role id by role name discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Does anyone know how to get the role ID from the role name?
I asked everyone, but he did not give the right answer

Please do not leave a negative rating for no reason, other people may have this problem!

```
@client.command()
async def createrole(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name="RGB")
    role_id = discord.utils.get(guild.roles,name="RGB")
    await ctx.send(role_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`create_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role) *returns* the role you just created. So

```py
@client.command()
async def createrole(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    new_role = await guild.create_role(name="RGB")
    role_id = new_role.id
    await ctx.send(role_id)
```

The [role object docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role).